# Faster way to display Jsoup Elements on Android

Tags: android, android-webview, jsoup

Is there a faster way to display Jsoup elements onto android apps?

The app I am working on download and parses a page using jsoup, gets a section of the page I want to display, edit some parts of it, then converts that section's element to HTML and displays it onto a webview.

Is there a faster way to do this? I noticed that getting the HTML from the elements takes a long time. Is there a way to directly add the element onto webview or something else without having to acquire its HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you're experiencing is a side effect of trying to do (relatively) complex processing on a *mobile* device. Keep in mind that your app may be installed on low-resource devices and stuff like this screams *low ratings*.

Having said that, you usually want to do these sort of complex transformations on the server side, and *then* send the (formatted) data to the device - which you can then render in your WebView, for example. There is no inherent way to [make jsoup faster](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8998753/1101070) - you're only limited by the resources of your device (as you already found out).